# A sufficient condition for being of the second category

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

A set $U$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be of the second category if $U$ is not a countable union of nowhere dense sets. Here is a sufficient condition for a subset to be of the second category from the textbook that I am trying to prove.

**Proposition:** $U$ is of the second category in $X$ if, whenever $U \subset \bigcup_n F_n$ with each $F_n$ close, at least one $F_n$ must have nonempty interior.

Please check my solution for correctness. Assume on the contrary that each $\text{Int} \ F_n =\emptyset$. Since $F_n$ is closed, each $F_n$ is nowhere dense. We can write $U$ as $U = \bigcup_n (U \cap F_n)$. If we can show that each $U \cap F_n$ is nowhere dense, then we are done (by contradiction). Since $(U \cap F_n) \subset F_n$, we have $\overline{U \cap F_n} \subset \overline{F_n}$. And so, $\text{Int }\overline{U \cap F_n} \subset \text{Int } \overline{F_n} = \emptyset$, and we have the desired contradiction.